# blueimp Gallery adding delete button under images always opens gallery

Tags: javascript, html, blueimp

I'm trying to add a delete button under my list of images that will delete the selected image from the gallery using Ajax.

The issue I’m having is that whenever the delete button is clicked it opens the gallery of images, the script below opens the gallery, which is opened when clicked inside of the 'links' div. So this is still initiating when I click on the Delete button but I’ve can’t seem to find away around it.

Script

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target.parentNode,
        options = { index: link, event: event },
        links = this.getElementsByClassName('image');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
```

Html

```
<div id="links">
        <div class="property-image">
            <a class="image" href="6e575f42-1da8-4da0-bf84-7752930aea75.JPG">
                <img src=" 6e575f42-1da8-4da0-bf84-7752930aea75.JPG">
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger delete-confirm-ajax close" data-ajax="true" data-id="72758" href=" ">Delete</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use the <input type="button"> instead of the anchor tag?

Comment: That doesn't work still fires the gallery as I'm clicking within the #links div.

Comment: what is supposed to be in the href of the anchor tag?

Comment: Have you tried this <input type="button" onclick="imageDeletionFunction()"> ?

Comment: Can't see that working either as the button would still be inside the #links div, i think the script may have to change how it works if anything.
The href will be the location/name of the action to delete the image as i'm using MVC.

Comment: do you have a fiddle or github url where i can test it?

Comment: Hi, i've just added it here https://jsfiddle.net/x51w717v/1/. So the delete button is at the bottom of the image, within the #links div.
So I require it so that the gallery doesn't open when the delete button is clicked on.

Comment: I am getting an error page instead of the fiddle

Comment: hmm, works fine for me - https://jsfiddle.net/x51w717v/1/

Comment: yeah it is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved your problem, at least in the fiddle it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/c5kbwqm0/2/

All I did was to focus the `click` event in the element `<a></a>` instead of the whole `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

patricia's answer will remove the functionality of the blueimp Gallery, didn't you notice you're not able to swipe to the next photo or close the modal?

Here is the completed solution https://jsfiddle.net/dfhjruft/, I'm using `if else` statement to detect whether is it button clicked or not.